# How to install clang-14 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c, g++, compiler, clang

Can you help me install clang-14 on Ubuntu 18.04? I think I need a valid repo as apt-get install clang-14 does not work.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS \n \l

$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get install clang-14
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-14

$ clang++ -v
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Not tested from me. Can be dangerous. https://apt.llvm.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clang-14` is not available for your release ... but [available as of Ubuntu 22.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang-14)

So, upgrading to 22.04 is what you might want to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Updating to Ubuntu 22.04 is not always possible. Both because there are a lot of performance downgrades that make it undesirable (snap everywhere, for example), but also because: on work servers, we can't just choose to upgrade, that's decided at a totally different organizational level.

Answer (score 10):

You can download clang 14 for  with the instructions on the llvm page here:

```
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh 14
```

Comment: It fails with the following:
`Distribution 'ubuntu' in version '18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)' is not supported by this script.`

Comment: It worked for me for clang-12 as well. just changed last line sudo ./llvm.sh 12

Answer (score 1):

You neded ubuntu-toolchain-r ppa in bionic

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

`wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh`

`chmod +x llvm.sh`

`sudo ./llvm.sh 14`

And now are installed with clang-14 and clang++-14 .

Comment: Would this allow installing Clang 16 on 22.04?