# How to install Clang 16 on 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, clang

I have 22.04 LTS but I'd like to install a later Clang, version 16.

How can I install this?

(22.04 doesn't come with Clang 16 in the repos)

UPDATE

Whilst I appreciate the answer below, I found a much simpler way from here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1415641/132414
https://apt.llvm.org/

```
To install a specific version of LLVM:
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh <version number>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cland 16 has pre-build packages available to download at its [github releases page](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-16.0.0).

In the case, you can select download the `clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz`  package for modern pc and laptop.

It's a non-install package, just extract it in your file manager, right-click on the **bin** sub-folder and select 'Open in Terminal'. Then run any executable file to compile your programs, such as `./clang-16 -x c++ ....`.

For any errors like below:

> error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

Search the key file (`libtinfo.so.5` in the case) in [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) under "Search the contents of packages" section. Then install the corresponding package (`libtinfo5` in the case).

And, if you use Clang 16 frequently, then you can add the '**bin**' into PATH. So, you don't have to navigate to that folder every time running clang-16 executable. There are quite a few tutorials talking about it. Here's [one that I made.](https://fostips.com/add-to-path-ubuntu/)